# Making Glassfish respond to OPTIONS HTTP-method call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, soap, glassfish

I'm trying to develop an HTML-page with Javascript/JQuery code that interacts with a SOAP web service running on Glassfish.

I'm trying to do the web service call as a POST HTTP-method request using AJAX. The problem is that the web service is running on a different server than where the page is served from, which, because of the cross-domain policy, results in my browser (Firefox) first doing an OPTIONS HTTP request to determine if the web service will allow the POST request. The web service running on Glassfish won't respond to this OPTIONS request.

I've seen that this can be configured in other application servers, by setting Access-Control-Allow-Origin to a pattern that recognizes all origins that should be accepted (for instance '*' to accept any request).
How do I make Glassfish respond to the OPTIONS request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided for now to avoid doing a cross-domain call (which should avoid the OPTIONS request from being sent) by deploying a proxy web service on the server on which the web page is hosted.

I don't have access to the server yet and I don't yet know a lot about it, so I hope that this will be possible to do.

Comment: For the record, I've deployed a PHP proxy web service on the hosting server. It works!

Answer (score 0):

Glasfish answeres to that OPTIONS request with:

```
   Response Header:
      X-Powered-By[Servlet/3.0]
      Server[GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.0.1]
      Allow[GET, HEAD, POST, TRACE, OPTIONS]
      Content-Length[0]
      Date[Wed, 30 Mar 2011 14:57:39 GMT]
```

So the question is: Where to add that additional HTTP-Header?
I've absolutely no idea! Maybe someone else can help?